# Can I use alternate controllers for Rock Band on my PS3? (i.e, my guitar-hero controllers)

Tags: ps3, rock-band, controllers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Guitar Hero peripherals work with Rock Band and vice versa?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4915/do-guitar-hero-peripherals-work-with-rock-band-and-vice-versa)

Subject pretty much says it all.  I've got PS3 + Rock Band, and would like to use Guitar-hero controllers.  Are there adapters?  Can I hack them, somehow?

Similarly, can I make my own controllers?  Are there sites with good DIY instructions?  By "make", I mean from scratch; I think I can figure out "buy a guitar, take it apart, put the bits into different plastics..."

Comment: Awww, that other question was a duplicate of this one, asked a month later!  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most work ... but not all.

- I think wired had the best
  [compatibility chart](http://www.wired.com/gamelife/2008/11/official-guitar/).
- Mods can become an obsession ... imho, [doc's forum](http://www.docsrockbandmods.com/) is the best

Answer (score 1):

What would you need an adapter for? If the Guitar Hero controllers are designed for the PS3, just plug them in and use them in Rock Band.

Comment: I use Guitar Hero controllers for Rock Band all the time-no adapter needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your Guitar Hero guitar controllers should work with Rock Band, as I do this all the time. You will require a software update for this to work. If your PS3 is connected to the Internet, you should be prompted for this the first time you play Rock Band.

I can't personally vouch for the other Guitar Hero peripherals, as I've not tried them, but they are supposed to be compatible.