# Can I use Rock Band 2 Intruments from the Wii on Xbox 360 / PS3?

Tags: nintendo-wii, rock-band-2

Since the Wii version of the instruments are connected to the console through USB, I was wondering if it was possible to use them on the other current consoles such as Xbox 360 and PS3.

I know that the game software doesn't carry over, I was just wondering about the hardware.

Comment: If you look at [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4915/do-guitar-hero-peripherals-work-with-rock-band-and-vice-versa "sweet") you'll see [this list](http://www.wired.com/gamelife/2008/11/official-guitar/ "useful") which should answer your question.

Comment: Not a direct duplicate, but it will probably get closed as such. The other question and charts linked to don't address the cross platform compatibility issue.

Comment: @Chris good point this is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: I saw the other question and it did not answer mine at all.

Answer (score 4):

Wii and Xbox controllers will not work with the other consoles.

- The "receiver" that the instruments plug into is just a USB hub since the consoles themselves don't have enough ports to support a full band's worth of instruments.
- All 3 major consoles (Xbox360, PS3 and Wii) use USB as the connection method for their controllers, but this doesn't mean the controllers send the same signals over USB in any way.
- Wii and Xbox360 controllers do not have the same button complement anyway, so even if they sent the same signals, you'd be missing buttons.  For example, all Xbox360 controllers of any size or shape must have the "Xbox" button that opens the Xbox HUD/blade thingy.

Answer (score 3):

The Wii and Xbox controllers aren't normally compatible so I can't see the instruments being either.

Comment: Not the Rock Band 2 instruments.  They don't use the Wii remotes at all.  Instead they come with a small receiver that is plugged into one of the USB ports of the Wii.  Each instrument communicates with the receiver.  I believe the Guitar Hero guitars for the Wii use the Wii remote (i.e. you have to plug the remote into the guitar).

Answer (score 2):

The USB receiver will be set up to run on a Wii. I highly doubt that an X-Box or PS3 would recognize it if you were to plug it in. They simply wont have the drivers, and the USB device wont be able to set itself up.

Theres also a good chance that each console takes input slightly differently. So even if it did work, theres no guarantee that pressing green on the Wii instrument will mean green to the X-Box.

I dont have any solid proof, but would be very *very* surprised if you got it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Only the microphones (or any other USB microphone) work across all platforms. The other peripherals are **controllers**, and you can't use a Wii controller on an Xbox 360.